# GeoServer GeoFence-Server WFS NullPointerException

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geoserver-geofence

I have a GeoServer (2.24.0) docker container with the GeoFence-server extension and it works fine until I connect to a QGIS and tried to update a point. After I press the save button, I get NullPointerException. If i remove the GeoFence entirely the flow works fine. I have these rights associated to admin [image]

[image]

Here are the logs:

```
21 Feb 17:25:53 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
21 Feb 17:25:53 INFO   [services.RuleReaderServiceImpl] - Requesting access for RuleFilter[user:"anonymous"+ role:ANY inst:name+:default-gs ip:"172.17.0.1"+ serv:"WFS"+ req:"DESCRIBEFEATURETYPE"+ sub:ANY ws:"ne"+ layer:"layer_65"+]
21 Feb 17:25:53 WARN   [services.RuleReaderServiceImpl] - No access for filter RuleFilter[user:"anonymous"+ role:ANY inst:name+:default-gs ip:"172.17.0.1"+ serv:"WFS"+ req:"DESCRIBEFEATURETYPE"+ sub:ANY ws:"ne"+ layer:"layer_65"+]
21 Feb 17:25:53 INFO   [services.RuleReaderServiceImpl] - Returning AccessInfo[grant:DENY admin:false] for RuleFilter[user:"anonymous"+ role:ANY inst:name+:default-gs ip:"172.17.0.1"+ serv:"WFS"+ req:"DESCRIBEFEATURETYPE"+ sub:ANY ws:"ne"+ layer:"layer_65"+]
21 Feb 17:25:53 INFO   [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Could not find type: {https://www.naturalearthdata.com}layer_65
at org.geoserver.wfs.DescribeFeatureType.run(DescribeFeatureType.java:155)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.describeFeatureType(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.describeFeatureType(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

**UPDATE
If I place the top rule: everyone can access everything from WFS it works. So QGIS is the problem. But how can I say to QGIS to use the same user you connected when making the requests?

Comment: You probably need to update the title to reflect your new problem